# Ifft and fft for sparse vectors

Tags: fft, ifft

I am trying to optimize some code for performance and i notice that i am forced to make a conversion from sparse to full vectors since the built-in ifft and fft functions do not support the sparse matrix type. My signal is however sparse and I want to exploit this fact.

Does anybody have a suggestion what you can do here?

Nithin

Comment: How does the sparceness ratio compare to log(N)/N ?

Comment: You could always calculate the Fourier-integral which goes O(N^2) rather than O (N log N). Per se the FFT is well defined over equally spaced data, so there is no trivial `sparse FFT`.

Comment: This varies per problem, but typically it will be very small compared log(N)/N.